# Is there anyway to assign the json result from an API call to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, openweathermap

Im learning javascript right now and working on a weather application using node and express. In short, I'm trying to use an api call from open weather map and assign it to a variable so I can access the values simlair to objects. I tried assigning the value to a variable but it doesnt print out the needed data when i try to access it.

```
var1=request.get(url, (error, response, body) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(json);

});

console.log(var1);//doesnt produce the data i need
```

Comment: No.  `request.get()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  It returns and continues running the lines of code after it BEFORE it calls its callback.  You have to use the `body` value inside the callback itself or call a function and pass it the `body` value from inside the function.  This is how asynchronous coding works in node.js.  The other structural option is to use `request-promise` instead and use `await` with the returned promise and it will get you more synchronous looking code (though its still asynchronous).

Comment: You may find it useful to read this [How do I return the response from an asychronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323).

Comment: There must be a few hundred duplicates of a question like this since this is such a common question.  I'd suggest do some searching here for "asynchronous", "synchronous", "await", "callback"

Answer (score 0):

You can if `request.get` returns a `Promise`:

Example:

```
const data = await request.get(url, (error, response, body);
```

Note that this only works if `request.get` returns a `Promise`. If it *does not*, check out some other node libraries for an HttpClient:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise